# MySQL multiple tables problem?

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to check my `email` if it equals `$e` but my email is in another table called `info` how can I can I fix this problem?

Here is my MySQL query so far.

```
"SELECT password, salt FROM users WHERE (email = '" . $e . "' OR username = '" . $e . "') AND active IS NULL"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JOIN:

```
SELECT users.password, users.salt
FROM users
JOIN info
ON info.id = users.info_id
WHERE (users.email = $e OR info.username = $e)
AND users.active IS NULL
```

Note: you may need to modify the line starting `ON` depending on how you have structured your schema. If you are unsure of what modification to make, update your question to include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE info`.

Also you might want to double-check that there isn't an SQL injection vulnerability in your code. It is good practice to use parameters, or at least make sure that the strings are properly [escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). It is not clear from your code extract if you are escaping correctly or not.

Comment: What's the SQL injection comment about?

Comment: @needHelp, it's about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and if you are asking what it is then your site might be facing a great risk.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov quick to jump to conclusions believe my I'm using a purifier and escaping my user inputted data.

Comment: You shouldn't escape your user inputted data. You should use parametrized queries.

Comment: @Mark Byers what is exactly supposed to happen before i go messing around with my database?

Comment: @needHELP: If you are not escaping correctly it should fetch passwords for all users. You can see how it works if you want, just substitute $e for the above string.

Comment: @needHELP: Great, that means either your system is safe from certain types of attack, you copied and pasted incorrectly, or I messed up the query. Hopefully the first of those options.

Comment: @Mark Byers I guess I could not win with you even if I did it correctly :(

Comment: @needHELp: PS: Did my suggestion of using a JOIN work for you?